# LXDE autostart not starting program

Tags: lxde

I have two programs that I want to autostart with LXDE-pi.  One starts but the other doesn't.  Here is my LXDE-pi

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@point-rpi
@/usr/local/bin/xastir
@/home/pi/ecs/ecsARM.bin
```

xastir starts perfectly in gui but the ecsARM.bin does not start correctly because it gives an error that a file is not found.  If immediately afterwards I enter /home/pi/ecs/ecsARM.bin in a terminal window it opens perfectly.  I can start ecsARM.bin as a service perfectly but not in LXDE-pi.  Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the script xastir that lock the console and doesn't exit.

You can confirm that problem (in your xastir script) if the issue disappears appending an & after the xastir call line.

The final output will be:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@point-rpi
@/usr/local/bin/xastir &
@/home/pi/ecs/ecsARM.bin
```